# On Image Hover Display text inside a box above image

Tags: css

I want text on image hover just like in this website. Using CSS3
https://addapinch.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this (just adopt the color and the divs)

Here is the `HTML`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 row_cont">
        <img class="image_box" src="path_to_the_image" id="image"/>
            <div id="overlay">
                <a href="#" class="link_hover">desired text</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 row_cont">
        <img class="image_box" src="path_to_the_image" id="image"/>
            <div id="overlay">
                <a href="#" class="link_hover">desired text</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 row_cont">
        <img class="image_box" src="path_to_the_image" id="image"/>
            <div id="overlay">
                <a href="#" class="link_hover">desired text</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 row_cont">
        <img class="image_box" src="path_to_the_image" id="image"/>
            <div id="overlay">
                <a href="#" class="link_hover">desired text</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the `CSS`:

```
.row_cont {
    position:relative;
    width:95%;
    height:240px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row_cont {
    position:relative;
    width:95%;
    height:240px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#image {
    position:absolute;
    width:95%;
    height:240px;
    /* background:black; */
}

#overlay {
    position:absolute;
    width:95%;
    height:240px;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .6s ease;
    -o-transition: all .6s ease;
    transition: all .6s ease;
}

#overlay:hover {
    opacity: .95;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 3px #000;
}

a.link_hover {
    position: relative;
    top: 45%;
    left: 13%;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: rgba(2, 103, 193, .7);
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

a.link_hover:hover {
    color: rgba(2, 103, 193, 1);
}

.image_box:hover {
    -ms-filter: blur(3px)!important;
    filter: blur(3px)!important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Let me know if it is this was helpful

Comment: i want small box with text on hover not full box on hover just like it is there in this website https://addapinch.com/

Comment: You need to try harder on your end. I cannot give you an end to end solution and do the work instead of you. You have a good start with my answer, just you need to adapt it a bit. Check the answer now, I have edited it.